# How to check if a variable has changed and if it is greater store it

Tags: javascript, compare, max, setinterval

I'm having a feed of the current altitude of a device assigned to the variable **measured_altitude** (updated every 500ms) and I want to keep the max. value that this has ever reached. It should be a simple if new value > old max value then new value = max value. But it doesn't seem to work. When comparing with a specific value, it works:

e.g.

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log("measured: " + measured_altitude);
    maxH = 50;
    if (measured_altitude > maxH) {
        console.log("new max");
        $("#max-height-value").text(measured_altitude);
        };

}, 1000);
```

but it doesn't when I'm trying to compare with the height.

Definitely a dumb question but I'm scratching my head for over an hour.

Comment: what is the console output?

Comment: Where are you storing the maximum value?

Comment: Shouldn't you be assigning the new height to `maxH` within your `if`? Currently you set it 50 every interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you goal, you need to assign the new height to `maxH` within your `if` and move the initial declaration outside of `setInterval`:

```
var maxH = 50; /* initial value (outside setInterval) */

setInterval(function () {
    console.log("measured: " + measured_altitude);

    if (measured_altitude > maxH) {
        maxH = measured_altitude; /* update if new value is larger */
        console.log("new max");
        $("#max-height-value").text(measured_altitude);
        };

}, 1000);
```